# Did Paul Richards (author of "The Unblessed") write anything else?

Tags: horror, authors

The book "[*The Unblessed*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1026505.The_Unblessed)" deals with the African spider demon Anansi.  It is based on a true legend from the Congo and I thought the book was fantastic and fascinating.

**Did the author (Paul Richards) write anything else?**

Comment: Totally off-topic, but if you like the character of Anansi, I recommend Neil Gaiman's novel about him, "Anansi Boys" :)

Answer (score 1):

Paul Richards maintains a website ([www.paulrichards.org](https://www.paulrichards.org/)). In addition to various biographical details, it lists two other books published by him, aside from *The Unblessed*.

One is a thriller novel, also set in Africa and the other appears to be some sort of relationship self-help manual.

> **[*Once and Forever in Africa*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0966631900)**
>
> For seven years, a rugged and pragmatic American privateer and his wife search for an epic lost gold mind in the most forbidding terrain on earth, the deep jungles of Liberia. ... This is the true story of a man who enters the ancient Africa, the Africa of mystery and beauty, and learns that once you are there, a part of you is there forever.(

and

> **[*Wild Attraction, The Energetic Facts of Life*](https://sentecenter.teachable.com/p/wild-attraction-the-energetic-facts-of-life)**
>
> A Ruthlessly Practical Guide to Extraordinary Relationship
> Wild Attraction springs from an energetically awakened couple's astonishing non-ordinary connection, and from seventeen years of teaching and coaching the skills needed to create extraordinary relationship.
>
> Wild Attraction is woven around 59 concise “Energetic Facts of Life”, each an overturning of a commonly held, but unworkable notion about the dynamics of male-female connection.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the right Paul Richards, he's a professor of Anthropology and he doesn't seem to have written any other fantasy books.
I did find one other book called *The President has been kidnapped*, but there's no description so I don't know if it's SciFi/Fantasy.
I found this list of his books [here](http://www.goodreads.com/author/list/62903.Paul_Richards) and [here](http://www.alibris.com/booksearch?browse=0&author=paul%20richards&mtype=B).

Comment: Hard to know if it is the same Paul Richards.  Its such a common name.

Comment: @ShlomoKirschner: I'm in full agreement.

Comment: This is not the correct Paul Richards; https://www.paulrichards.org/career-overview